# The spreading game and its expansion

Tags: logic, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorial-geometry, algorithmic-game-theory, chessboard

### For all those who lost their lives and due to this tragic disease

---

**CONTEXT**

This question is inspired by the following question that was proposed by my math teacher Lam Nguyen, I shall cite this exactly as it's origin:

> Assume that there is a $2m\times2n$ table. The governor and the Coronavirus play a game. In their respective moves, the governor and the virus quarantine a square that is formed by multiple unit squares (its size  can vary). The first player who does not have a legal move loses the game. The governor moves first. Proves that no matter how the virus spreads, the governor always has a winning strategy.

Now it is very clear that the table can be divided in to 4 separate parts. If the governor picks the $2\times2$ square in the center of the table, then the table still consists of 4 identical parts. Now what the governor has to do is to pick the squares symmetrically through the table's centre.

**!note that** by picking at the center first, the player has avoided the fact that the center square is a reflection of itself through the center.

I doubt the applicability of this strategy in this following problem

**EXPANSION 1**

What is the minimal casualty that the COVID-19 virus can cause regarding a $4038\times4040$ table

**EXPANSION 2**

Provides a $2m\times2n$ table, and 2 players A and B starts moving from 2 opposite corners of the rectangle (2 corners that lies on the same diagonal). In each move, each player inhabit an adjacent square that:

- Is formed of unit squares
- Must share at least one unit side with one of the squares that player occupied.

The one who makes the last move wins. Player A moves first

**Post script**

Now I suppose that A and B cannot use the "symmetric" strategy now. But I assume that A still win because he can determine the situation by the first moves. It could also be depending on the value of m and n.

Comment: On a $2\times4$ board, I believe the second player wins.

Comment: I am curious: what is the smallest percentage of casualties (the ratio number of infected squares to the total number of squares) that the government can guarantee?  The same strategy seems to work if the board is of size $(2m-1)\times (2n-1)$.  The government picks the central $1\times 1$ square first, and then play symmetrically w.r.t. the virus's moves.  Not sure about a general $m\times n$ board.  Is there an $m\times n$ board that the virus can win?

Comment: @saulspatz, No, if the first person picks a $2\times2$ table then he definitely loses. So he picks the $1\times1$ table. Now if the second player picks a $2\times2$ table then there are 3 squares left, so he loses. So he has to go with $1\times1$. Then the first person picks the $2\times2$ square in the center and he wins

Comment: Yes @WETutorialSchool, I think your question is very interesting. I did not see that coming. But well it depends on the value of $2\times(m-n)$ which we do not know, I think.

Comment: In your first game, any first move symmetric across the centre is a winning move for the reason you give, and then the sides do not have to be even.  The biggest first move seems to be to take the largest possible square symmetric across the centre and gains that area and at least half the rest

Comment: Both your teacher's and your versions of the game are interesting.  Do you know at least what happens in a general $m\times n$ board in your teacher's rule?   If $(m,n)=(1,2k)$, then the virus wins.  Who wins if $m>1$ is odd and $n$ is even?

Comment: It's true, but I cited that exactly as the origin so thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Yes, in my teacher rule, as @Henry mentioned, does not have to be even. But it is going to be more complicated to find out the center of the table. After that symmetry is used the same way. I think my teacher designed this for 7 or 8 graders so it should not be too hard for them.

Comment: In your teacher's rule for an $m\times n$ board with $m\equiv n\pmod{2}$, the government can always win and occupy at least $\left(\frac{m+n}{2}\right)\min\{m,n\}$ squares.  The virus has a strategy to infect at least $\left(\frac{|m-n|}{2}\right)\min\{m,n\}$ squares.

Comment: I will add this issue to my problem and please write a full answer to it. And do me a favor and upvote this post

Comment: This is a great game but I would be careful about calling it "Government vs Coronavirus," lest people think it is a realistic model for the actual phenomenon.

Comment: @j0equ1nn I didn't realised someone edited the name.

Comment: @minhtrungdang Now that you know, you can edit it back.

Comment: @j0equ1nn I have changed it. Have you considered giving me a solution to this problem?

Comment: Great! I've been very busy with other work related to the coronavirus, which is how I came upon the post.

Answer (score 2):

Per OP's request, I am writing a solution for the game on an $m\times n$ board under the **teacher's rule** (the government and the virus can occupy anywhere on the board).  When $m\equiv n\pmod{2}$, the government has a winning strategy that guarantees that it occupies at least $\left(\frac{m+n}{2}\right)\min\{m,n\}$ unit squares.  The virus has a strategy to infect  at least $\left(\frac{|m-n|}{2}\right)\min\{m,n\}$ unit squares.

Wlog, suppose that $m>n$.  The government's first move is to occupy the central $2\times 2$ square when $m$ and $n$ are even, or the central $1\times 1$ square when $m$ and $n$ are odd.  Then the government copies the virus move symmetrically about the board's center.  This is a winning strategy of the government.

However, the government can maximize its occupied territory with the first move being the occupation of the central $n\times n$ square.  This leaves $(m-n)n$ unit squares to be dealt with, and the strategy of symmetric moves against the virus guarantees that the government can take at least have of the remaining unit squares.  That is, the government can aim to occupy at least $$n^2+\frac{(m-n)n}{2}=\left(\frac{m+n}{2}\right)n$$ unit squares.

On the other hand, the virus plays the greedy algorithm.  That is, in every turn, it infects a square of the largest possible size.  If the first move by the government is to take over a $k\times k$ square (clearly, $k\le n$), then the virus can take at least half of the remaining area.  Hence, the virus has a strategy to infect at least
$$\frac{mn-k^2}{2}\geq \frac{mn-n^2}{2}=\left(\frac{m-n}{2}\right)n$$
unit squares.

P.S.  The situation where $m\not\equiv n\pmod{2}$ is a bit complicated.  For $(m,n)=(2k,1)$, the virus wins (and each player occupies half of the board).  But for $(m,n)=(3,2)$, the government wins and is able to occupy all but one unit square.  I have no idea about this problem if the OP's rule (the players start from opposite corners of the board, and each can only play a square adjacent to previously played squares) is used.

Comment: @MinhTrungDang I think it is premature to accept this as an answer.  A large part of your question is still open.  When you accept an answer, people may think that you don't need help anymore.  So, I recommend that you unaccept my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was not quite familiar with how this page work. Beg your pardon. Please help me develop the final answer.